# Delete values from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

On my app I read some values that I added to the database and I insert them into a spinner. I want to delete any value I want but the error message ways there is no column with that name. Even though my spinner fills up with values. Error message:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bmw (code 1), while compiling: DELETE FROM MyCars WHERE MyCarsBrand=bmw at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement
```

Here is my code:

```
            if (db.deleteTitle(deleteSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()))
                Toast.makeText(DeleteCarActivity.this,
                        "Delete successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(DeleteCarActivity.this, "Delete failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.close();
```

Other class

```
    public boolean deleteTitle(String rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(MY_CARS_TABLE, MY_CARS_BRAND_COLUMN + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return db.delete(MY_CARS_TABLE, MY_CARS_BRAND_COLUMN + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 1;
```

with

```
return db.delete(MY_CARS_TABLE, MY_CARS_BRAND_COLUMN + 
                "='" + rowId + "'", null) > 1;
```

You need '' around string arguments.

Comment: I hate it when it comes to these much detail. Thank you m8. It worked.